# send a data.json file to node.js from postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postman

I want to send a `data.json` file, stored on my desktop to a node.js function. The structure of my `data.json` file is:

```
[{"key":"value"}, {same key value structure for 8000 entries}]
```

It's a contact book which basically stores name and contact number  in both in string format and also all of these store inside an array. It's lots of json objects into array. Now i want to send it to my backend (node.js with express) and store it in a variable.

I am trying like this using postman, I put the file in form data and send it to my express api.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, response) {
      console.log(data);
      response.send(data);
});
```

But it logs to the console as an empty object like so `{}`.

I hope I explained my problem.

Comment: what have you tried in the frontend?

Comment: You should use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) in the backend with this you will be able to store the file and get its content.

Comment: Can you please show your Postman request?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar i am using postman for sending a file.

Comment: @codeinaire ok ill post that in a bit.

Comment: ok @ApoorvaChikara ill try that this time and then i ll tell you if i get some progress.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML,

```html
<input name="file" type="file" (change)=filechanged($event)/>
```

In typescript,

```js
filechanged(e) {
  this.file = e.target.files[0];
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    this.Name = fileReader.result;
    this.data = this.Name;
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
}

submit() {
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

You send this `formdata` through API

In Backend,

```js
app.post("/upload", function (req, response) {
  var data = JSON.parse(req.body.file);
  response.send(data);
});
```